# Possible error in Mathematica's NMinimize function

Tags: runtime-error, wolfram-mathematica

Can anybody verify that the following is a real Mathematica problem and I am not fooling myself.
The problem is that `NMinimize` in the following code does not give any error message nor any results.

I am running Windows 10 Build 1809 and Mathematica 12.0
The code runs as expected if `n<180`. But if `n>=180` `NMinimize` does not give any output, no error, no results. Please note that I have more than enough memory (32GB), so it is not a memory problem.

```js
n = 180;
a = -1; b = 1; fa = 1;
xs = Range[a, b, (b - a)/n];
ys = Subscript[y, #] & /@ xs;
y1 = Differences[ys]; y1 = (Most[y1] + Rest[y1])/2;
y2 = Differences[ys, 2];
ys = ys[[2 ;; -2]];
eq = ((y1^2 + y1^4 - ys y2)^2 - 1 + y1^2).((y1^2 + y1^4 - ys y2)^2 - 
      1 + y1^2) /. {Subscript[y, a] -> fa, Subscript[y, b] -> fa};
NMinimize[eq, ys]
```

Comment: If it helps you in any way, I can reproduce this. At exactly `n=180` this code causes my Mathematica 12.0.0 kernel on Ubuntu x64 to crash on the `NMinimize` line. Values below that seem to be fine. Also note that there is https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ specifically for Mathematica questions, in case you don't get an answer here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I wanted to be sure before reporting an error to Wolfram. Daniel

Comment: Just to make that clear: I have not checked the code in any way, it just popped up in the review queue and I had a mathematica instance at hand. I don't know if you exceeded any kind of imposed limit or memory or anything like that.

Comment: Kernel also crashes on "12.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (July 23, 2019)"